# Am I doing my read() and write() correctly of my sockets?

Tags: c

```
void find_factor(int sockfd)
{
    unsigned long factor = 1ul;
    unsigned long task_info[3];
    memset(task_info, 0, sizeof(task_info)); /*Set array elements to zero*/
    //TODO: insert an appropriately parameterized call to read()
    //      in order to read the task_info data sent from the server via
    //      the file descriptor sockfd.
    //read(); //reads in the number task_info
    read(sockfd,task_info,sizeof(task_info));

    printf("Node is to test numbers %lu modulo %lu to factor %lu\n",task_info[0],task_info[1],task_info[2]);

    unsigned long numOfPrimes = 0ul;
    unsigned long maxCheck = sqrt( task_info[2] );
    for (unsigned long ii = task_info[0]; ii <= maxCheck; ii+=task_info[1]){
            if(task_info[2]%ii == 0){
                    factor = ii;
            }
    }
    //TODO: append an appropriately parameterized call to write
    //      in order to communicate the computed candiate factor to the server
    //      via the file descriptor sockfd.
    //write();
    write(sockfd,task_info,3);
}
```

The code above is the client side for my program that connects to a server with sockets. I am meant to read and write the task_info for the program, but I am sure I did it wrong based on the output. Is there something I should fix?

Comment: Assuming TCP, 'read(sockfd,task_info,sizeof(task_info));' .may read only one byte...

Answer (score 2):

No — you are not using `write()` correctly, though you did use `read()` correctly, except for the absence of error checking.

You have:

```
unsigned long task_info[3];
…
write(sockfd,task_info,3);
```

This writes just 3 bytes of data instead of 12 or 24 — the correct value mainly depends on whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit system.  You need to use `sizeof(task_info)` for the number of bytes to `write()`, just as you did in the `read()` call for the number of bytes to read:

```
if (write(sockfd, task_info, sizeof(task_info)) != sizeof(task_info))
    …report error…
```

You should add a similar error check to the `read()` call too.

You could mess around with checking how much data was written (capture the result from `write()` instead of just testing it) and if some of the data was not written, then you could attempt to write the remainder, stopping the loop if all the data is written successfully, or stopping the loop with an error if no bytes are written (return value 0) or if you get an error returned (return value -1).  The 0 case is pretty unlikely.  That would be relevant in commercial code or with big messages; it probably isn't relevant for a school exercise (except perhaps for bonus points).  Use your favourite web search engine with 'writen c function' and see what comes up; Google provides a number of plausible links.